# Android add textview at the bottom of listview in drawerlayout

Tags: android, listview, view, navigation-drawer

my layout contains a drawerlayout with a fragment container and a listview. The listview contains three items, which I've added with an adapter.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@drawable/listview_background_drawable"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

So now I want to add a view to the bottom of the listview (screen). I tried it with addFooterView(), but this just add the view under the last item and not at the bottom of the screen. I now there are a few examples on stackoverflow how to do it but they don't work for me, because of my drawerlayout.

Is there a way to add the view to my listview and set the alignment of the view to the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the bottom layout should be taken out of the `ListView`. You need to enclose all your elements inside a parent layout (preferably a a `RelativeLayout`) and declare the `DrawerLayout` and your bottom layout inside it. Also, set android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" for the bottom Layout so that it always remains at the bottom.

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...
    ... >
    (put your drawer layout xml here)

    <BottomLayout
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    </BottomLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @ihsan but the main layout would must be "<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout", not RelativeLayout?

Comment: @ihsan but in this case, I always see the BottomLayout in the screen, it isn't hidden with slider menu ... how can I show BottomLayout only when slider menu is visible?

Comment: @KryNac put in your DrawerLayout a RelativeLayout and inside this your BottomLayout with the attribute android:layout_alignParentBottom="true". Now your BottomLayout will only be visible if the drawer is open.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding a layout as footerview to listview or use this code just change the header to footer.

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#AA000000"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <com.wholesaleraja.model.RoundImage
                android:id="@+id/profile_icon"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/default_image_male" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_name_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_email"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/header_divider"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_view"
            android:background="@color/list_divider" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_divider"
            android:background="@color/list_header"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: @RyuZz - please, can you mark it correct. So, that others can also see this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set your drawer as a Layout and place the list and other views inside it. For instance:

```
<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_background_drawable"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The slider menu could be any type of view, so you colud make something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_background_drawable"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: The closing tag for  <LinearLayout/> should be   </LinearLayout> right?